# Generating a unique 10 digit phone number

Tags: oracle, function, unique

My goal is to generate a random 10 digit unique phone number function.

Is there a way to ensure the first digit isn't  a zero(0)? Second, I want to wrap this in a function to do a test like NOT IN OR NOT EXISTS before adding the phone number.

I came up with the following so far but can use some help on implementing the other requirements.

```
CREATE TABLE PHONE_NUMBERS
(
   PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO PHONE_NUMBERS (PHONE_NUMBER)
SELECT listagg(ROWNUM-1,'') WITHIN GROUP ( 
order by (dbms_random.random )) mydigit FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

Comment: It's easier to use `round` with `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(
  low  IN  NUMBER,
  high IN  NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER `

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Don't use `ROUND` as you will not get an equal distribution as the lowest and highest values will be half as likely to occur as the intermediate values ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d8eb98e329e05f9a1690d795a24cdcc3)).  Use `FLOOR` or `TRUNC` with the `high` value one higher than the required maximum.

Comment: @MT0 to be honest the same fix you can use with round - just shift your bounds to 0.5: use 0.5 for low and 10.5 for high

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate numbers from `1000000000` to `9999999999999`, you can use:

```sql
FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1e9, 1e10))
```

If you want to insert values without inserting duplicates then use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO phone_numbers dst
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1e9, 1e10)) AS phone_number
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
) src
ON (src.phone_number = dst.phone_number)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (phone_number)
  VALUES (src.phone_number);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=91f07537c33d4c81bafd949cb98408f1)*

Comment: When the number of used phone numbers will be high, such approach will have a very low chance to get the next number and this problem will be much more significant than non-balanced distribution on edge values mentioned in the previous comment. It would be better to allocate all the numbers first, add `not_used` flag with `null` for used phone number and index on that flag. Then you may issue `select` with filter on the flag and `rownum` and get available number without test of each value. I assume that distribution is not the core point in this task